# Accessing ID's from an active but not main layout

Tags: java, android, layout, tabs

I use a tabview in my main layout where every tab has it's own layout. Now when I want to declare a button in my first tab layout I get a nullPointerException because the ID of this button is not found in my main layout.
So to explain in code when I use:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

And the button is in the layout of my first tab I will get a NullPointerException because the code chooses my main layout over my first tab layout.

What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: What code do you want me to post then? The rest of the code doesn't really give more information.

Comment: You can inflate your tablayout first, then use `teblayout.findViewById(R.id.button1)`

Comment: @JoppeD If you post complete code then I can find where is your mistake and try to provide solutions..

Comment: @withparadox2 can you please explain me how to inflate my tablayout? I've seen something about this but it didn't work for me so maybe you have a different way of doing it

Comment: `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`
`ViewGroup layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_tab_layout, null);`
`Button button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button1)`

Comment: @withparadox2 what do I need to put in context? And what is the second argument from the layoutinflater.inflate method?

Comment: You can pass an Activity instance as a context, if you inflate it in your activity you can just pass `this` as context, for `Activity` extends from `Context`. It comes from `public View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)`, set `root=null` means you don't want make any `root` view as the parent of your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem with the help of withparadox2.
This is the code I used:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
ViewGroup firstTab = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab_fragment, null);
```

I had to put this after the onCreate() and instead of `findViewById()` I now use `firstTab.findViewById()`